# cannot fetch images using camera android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

The application, is supposed to get an image from Camera or Gallery (user's choice) then, upload it to server.
There's no problem with getting an image from the gallery and uploading it to server.
The problem here is retrieving an image taken by the camera !

```
public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button UploadBn;
private ImageButton ChooseBn, CameraBn;
private EditText NAME;
private ImageView imgView;
private CameraPhoto cameraPhoto;
private GalleryPhoto galleryPhoto;
final int CAMERA_REQUEST=13323;
final int GALLERY_REQUEST=22131;
private String selectedPhoto;
private Bitmap bitmap = null;
private String UploadUrl="http://localhost/webapp/getImg.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

    NAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    UploadBn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadBn);
    ChooseBn=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ivGallery);
    CameraBn=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ivCamera);
    imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    cameraPhoto = new CameraPhoto(getApplicationContext());
    galleryPhoto = new GalleryPhoto(getApplicationContext());
    ChooseBn.setOnClickListener(this);
    UploadBn.setOnClickListener(this);
    CameraBn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.ivGallery:
                selectImageGalerie();
            break;

        case R.id.uploadBn:
            if(NAME==null || imgView.getDrawable()==null)
                Toast.makeText(this,"select an image, give it a name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                uploadImage();
            break;
        case R.id.ivCamera:
            selectImageCamera();
            break;
    }
}

private void selectImageGalerie() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
}

private void selectImageCamera() {
    try {
        startActivityForResult(cameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent(), CAMERA_REQUEST);
        cameraPhoto.addToGallery();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Somathing Wrong while taking photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private String imageToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] imgBytes=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

private void uploadImage() {
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UploadUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, response , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            imgView.setImageResource(0);
            imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            NAME.setText("");
            NAME.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name",NAME.getText().toString().trim()+".jpg");
            params.put("encoded",imageToString(bitmap));
            return params;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getInstance(UploadActivity.this).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && data != null){
        if(requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST) {
            Uri path = data.getData();
            galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(path);
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), path);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                String photoPath=cameraPhoto.getPhotoPath();
                selectedPhoto=photoPath;
            try {
                    Log.d("BITMAP ==", "AWEL EL TRY");
                    bitmap= ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(300,300).getBitmap();
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something Wrong while choosing photos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        NAME.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.d("BITMAP ==", "E5ER EL TRY");
    }
}
```

}

After performing some tests, I found out that the variable *data* is **null** so it skips all the *if()* statement in the *onActivityResult()* method. 
It doesn't make sense, why would the camera not return a value even though I took a picture !

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "the problem" is.

Comment: when trying to retrieve a picture shot with the camera in an android application, I'm able to access the camera and take a shot. But, when the intent is returned to the onActivityResult(), an imageView named : imgView is supposed to display that image. What really happens, the activity stays the same and no update is made
 I edited the post check it out again.

Comment: Hello, can you show me what have you written inside takePhotoIntent() method?

Comment: @nishon: I cannot its a method in a library I downloaded while following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LCnoVqQ6N4)

Answer (score 2):

> why would the camera not return a value even though I took a picture

If you provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on the `Intent`, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not need to return a result. I assume that is what `takePhotoIntent()` does.

Moreover, the rest of your code for the `requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST` branch does not use the `data` `Uri` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello for a quick fix try the provided code and for more in-depth learning read this https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Call captureImage() method instead of selectImageCamera() on R.id.uploadBn button click.

```
 private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video
 public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
  private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "MyPhotos";
```

> Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app request image capture

```
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

> Creating file uri to store image/video

```
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}
```

> Returning image

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }



// Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

    }
    return mediaFile;
}
```

> Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the
>   camera

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
             previewCapturedImage();

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

> Display image from a path to ImageView

```
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {

        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I am updated my answer with getOutputMediaFileUri() and getOutputMediaFile()